# The Closest Solder to Radio Shack Solder

Tags: soldering

Does anyone have an opinion or otherwise 'proven notion' of the closest alternative to Radio Shack solder? Please, only answer this question by your own experience, as tons of options out there say "60/40." Specifically, I am after the kind of Radio Shack solder that says, "PC Work SN 60/PB 40, 60/40 Rosin-Core Solder," "6400006."

Comment: I am new to Stack Exchange and appreciate the answer I checked as an answer. Duly. I tried "Aim" solder from Mouser.com, Sn60/Pb40, 0.05", 3% rosin and it was nearly identical to the "pc-work" solder I ran out of from Radio Shack. Their (the "Shack") store now has solder available, yet I can recommend the above mentioned as a replacement. It is the 'only' solder I have used that compares, so far, albeit I never tried "Kester." I usually only tried other welding compounds sourced less expensively from over seas, even though I consider lead-free solder to be a different animal, altogether. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about [that solder](https://www.amazon.ca/Radio-Shack-Rosin-Core-Solder-1-5/dp/B007Z7QFDM).

[image]

It is 60% tin, 40% lead solder with RA (activated rosin) flux core that is 0.050" (1.27mm) in diameter.

Any good quality solder that is close to those three details will be as good or better.

Personally, I prefer slightly more expensive 63/37 eutectic alloy with RA flux such a Kester 44, but there are plenty of other options such as Multicore.

If you live in a place that has restricted the use of lead-based solder they may be hard to find. Lead-free solders are a bit harder to work with and have a higher melting point.

Some imported solder may not be the pure alloy that you would expect from a brand name. If you buy brand-name solder from a proper electronics distributor you will not likely have any problems. Buying from dubious sources will increase your chances of disappointment enormously.

Comment: The link you gave me connects to a page that shows r-shack solder to be unavailable; the online r-shack store does not have any solder available, currently. I do appreciate your answering my question and have only been a part of this website for a few hours. I may try the above mentioned solder, sometime; I ordered "Aim Sn60/Pb40" off mouser with rosen core 3% (a few moments ago), while the r-shack kind is rated 2%. We'll see how that goes - a joyous day it is when we can live and learn together. :)

Comment: Just to be clear, I linked the page to give credit for the photo (and list the known specifications), not to suggest a supplier (that's considered very much off-topic here). Whether the core has 2% or 3% flux is not a big deal. Kester makes 2.2 and 3.3%. I would find the diameter of that solder to be too large for most purposes, typically 0.6 to 1.0mm is better for smaller parts. 0.05" would be more' suitable for large through-hole parts on a crude board. Good solders are guaranteed meet national or international standards as far as purity goes. The Radio Shack one does not appear to.

Comment: Thank you kind master; I will be saving for the book on your profile.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you, again [ty]. The "Aim" solder I got from Mouser works perfectly. I look forward to reading and answering and asking questions on Stack Exchange, sometimes. :)